# Convert HTML files to epub files programmatically ( command line ubuntu )

Tags: linux, html, epub

Is it possible to convert a HTML5 file or text to epub file via a unix command line ? 
Is it possible to automate this process ??

thanks

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can try [pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/)

```
sudo apt-get install pandoc
pandoc -f html -t epub3 -o output.epub input.html
```

You can add metadata for epub:

```
pandoc -f html -t epub3 --epub-metadata=metadata.xml -o output.epub input.html
```

Metadata xml file: [metadata.xml](http://www.idpf.org/epub/30/spec/epub30-ocf.html#sec-container-metainf-metadata.xml)

Answer (score 14):

Another option is using the following after installing [calibre](https://calibre-ebook.com/download_linux).

```
ebook-convert  input.html output.epub
```

I found some break lines errors with pandoc, that didn't happen with ebook-convert

[Source](https://askubuntu.com/questions/797575/is-there-any-command-line-software-to-create-e-books-from-the-scratch-in-ubuntu)

Comment: And to add metadata and cover, you can use ebook-meta in combination with ebook-convert